# Locating what lib is linking to the debug CRT

Tags: c++, visual-c++

We link our app with numerous different static libs, the problem is that one of these libs is in turn linking with the VC90.DebugCRT even in release. Some libs we don't even have the source to, so it would be nice if there's a way to locate what lib is the actual culprit. I've toyed around some with dumpbin, but am unable to find a way to track down the offending lib.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The linker's [/verbose:lib](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdsk6as6(VS.80).aspx) can help.  Recompile your entire solution with this option set under  Project>Properties>Linker>Command Line and look through the log to see who links with who.

Answer (score 0):

To find out about dependencies required by specific modules try using [Dependency Walker](http://dependencywalker.com/) *"Dependency Walker is a free utility that scans any 32-bit or 64-bit Windows module (exe, dll, ocx, sys, etc.) and builds a hierarchical tree diagram of all dependent modules"*

Comment: The question is about static libraries, not Win32 portable executables.

Answer (score 0):

The **dumpbin** command delivered with MSVC can show which libs a lib will use to link.
I am not completely sure at the moment but I think

```
dumpbin /DEPENDENTS thirdpartylib.lib
```

will do the job.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/c1h23y6c%28VS.80%29.aspx